# langid.map.individual not working in solr

Tags: solr, language-detection

I am trying to perform multiple language detections on fields in document submitted to solr. This is my solrconfigxml for language identification:

```
 <updateRequestProcessorChain name="langid">
   <processor class="org.apache.solr.update.processor.LangDetectLanguageIdentifierUpdateProcessorFactory">
     <str name="langid.fl">title,description</str>
     <str name="langid.langField">language</str>
     <str name="langid.langsField">languages</str>
     <bool name="langid.map">true</bool>
     <bool name="langid.map.keepOrig">true</bool>
     <str name="langid.whitelist">cjk,ckb,ar,bg,ca,cz,da,de,el,en,es,et,eu,fa,fi,fr,ga,gl,hi,hu,hy,id,it,ja,ko,lv,nl,no,pt,ro,ru,sv,tr</str>
     <str name="langid.fallback">tg</str>
     <bool name="langid.map.individual">true</bool>
     <str name="langid.map.individual.fl">websiteKeywords,websiteDescription,websiteTitle,websiteContent</str>
   </processor>
   <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory" />
   <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
 </updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

I detect the language of the document based on `title` and `description` field. That part works as expected as I solr creates 2 new fiels `title_languagecode` and `description_languagecode`, for example `title_en` and `description_en`. I also wanted to separately detect the language of `websiteKeywords, websiteDescription, websiteTitle, websiteContent` and map the fields to `websiteKeywords_en, websiteDescription_en, websiteTitle_en, websiteContent_en`. With current configuration, that does not happen. Solr only stores original fields, that is `websiteKeywords, websiteDescription, websiteTitle, websiteContent`. What am I doing wrong? Your help is much appreciated. I am using solr 8.9.0.

Answer (score 1):

I misunderstood what `langid.map.individual` and `langid.map.individual.fl` represent. `langid.map.individual.fl` is a subset of `langid.fl`. If the specified fields are not in `langid.fl` it will have no effect. `langid.map.individual` refers to fields in `langid.fl` or the subset specified in `langid.map.individual.fl`.